# How to use moment.js in pug? Property or method "moment" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, pug

I am using PugJs, VueJs and MomentJs to format my date. This project is not a Single File Component.

Here is my code

```
div {{ moment(currentEvent.date).format('DD MMMM YYYY')  }}
```

I have already added the library

```
script(src!= ASSET_PATH.js + "/vendor/moment.min.js")
```

But when I run, I got the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that including the library inside the `<template> </template>` will work, it's not a pug problem.

##### Try this:

1 - Delete this line `script(src!= ASSET_PATH.js + "/vendor/moment.min.js")`.

2 - Install [momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) with `npm` or `yarn`.

3 - now at the top inside the `<script> </script>` import it like so: `import moment from 'moment'`

Comment: sorry, i forget to mention that mine is not Single File Components

Comment: Another solution would be to look at the index.html inside `public` folder. And add it like so `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: still the same error